# Segregate tightly coupled frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, html, flask, web-applications, web-deployment

`Python-2.7, Web Framework : Flask`

> My frontend and backend are present on the same server. I am using flask web framework( GET/POST APIs and also render templates). Now I want to segregate them and host them in two different machines. Since the code base is tightly coupled and I am mostly rendering HTML files, How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are rendering html right from your server you still can decentralize your frontend and backend. Create your backend server with a REST API or something similar. Then for your frontend server simply have it make calls to the backend server and return those results rendered in html for the client. That way you don't need to expose your backend server if you don't want to.

Here is an example:

**Backend**

```
@app.route('/mydata/')
def mydata:
    # ... logic/service calls ...
    return jsonify(result)
```

**Frontend**

```
import requests

@app.route('/')
def index():
    api_result = requests.get(API_URL + '/mydata/')
    # ... Map api_result to result ...
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Comment: You mean that instead of rendering, we can make an Ajax call from the html file itself to the backend REST API and get the data, is that right ?

Comment: It would make a call from your view then passed into your template. Though there will still be code in your frontend project, it would not have any of your backend logic.

Comment: okay, I will try implementing this. One question though separating the two(frontend and backend) will add additional overhead when it comes to webpages right ?

Comment: I should clarify - The typical way this is typically accomplished is using purely "Ajax" calls from the view. My solution is minimal changes on your part, because instead of getting the data and mutating the view client side it gets the data before it sends out the view server side.

Comment: Yes, there will be more overhead, but in most cases it's negligible.

Comment: In the example above [front end] Is it a good practice to make a GET request inside a view ?

Comment: If you are building a larger application, I would factor the API requests out of the view into a separate service, otherwise I would put it right in the view.

Comment: Does it make sense to just have a proxy pass  Redirecting it to my existing backend server?

Comment: If you mean any existing ajax calls that you use, I think that could be a valid solution, or just expose your backend server and use a different url for it.